# connecting to webmin gui remotely via ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunnel, webmin

I have an instance of webmin running inside our office.  Within the building I can access via the browser using the ip and port 10000 (as is standard)

Outside the building, the router is not set up to forward port 10000, and I would rather not.  However, port 80, 443, and an ssh port (not 22, but another "secret" port) are forwarded.

I am trying to tunnel over SSH with no luck.  Is it possible to forward "temporarily" port 10000 from my local browser over SSH to port 10000 on the remote server?

I have tried

```
ssh -p 1234 -D 10000 user@public.url
ssh -p 1234 -L 10000:public.url:10000 user@public.url
ssh -p 1234 -L 10000:localhost:10000 user@public.url
```

maybe more combinations of localhost, ip addresses, and urls to no avail.

Is it possible?  What command am I looking for?  I have used this trick to "browse" port 80 of remote dev computers, but can't figure out how to get port 10000 of webmin.

Answer (score 0):

The correct tunnelling command is `ssh -p 1234 -L 10000:localhost:10000 user@public.url` (note the `-p 1234` is only required because ssh is not on the standard port 22, also `localhost` can be swapped with the local/internal IP address of the server)

The problem was the URL I was putting into my local browser.  I don't know why, but the only URL that worked to connect to webmin was `https://localhost:10000`

hope this helps someone else.  I tried this a dozen times and only today figured it out.

Comment: Why is because the local port is bound on `localhost`, i.e. your machine, thus that is where your web browser must connect to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton not sure I follow, any url I enter with port 10000 should go through or to the remote server.  On the remote server the hosts file contains 3 different "url" that point to 127.0.0.1 and it's own local ip should all work to reach itself.

Comment: Yes, but you are not on the remote server, you are on your local computer!